# Sending Push Notifications to Safari from Java

Tags: java, push-notification, safari, web-push, safari-push-notifications

I am trying to get the Web Push API to work with my app and Safari on iOS. I can register fine in Safari ... But, when trying to send my request to the endpoint I receive a 403 with reason: BadJwtToken.
I've verified the token being sent in the Authentication header is valid. Also, the code I am using to send the Push request works perfectly on Chrome & Edge.
Has anyone else experienced this behaviour? Excerpt from the log below showing outgoing request and response. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /QKmekz9T3h2DpblQXdmVpVJPWtR145PdK-WYRMt4zldrXBOGsnqLluGtB9PFehMfoTXASt2-8pTmnRzUB0P0XMMDgX-tWdgIvL1YptpQdI_pVB3EEsnbR0LUStq97BUMIrMG_yVI6eUYJVigQtVgq0Fcl0D8k7tt9U8WEBbLmFc HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: WebPush eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3dlYi5wdXNoLmFwcGxlLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTY3NzIxMzEyNSwic3ViIjoibWFpbHRvOiA8aW5mb0BtZHNnbG9iYWwuY29tPiJ9.7P42kj123WHHWk0AaRiFiIb1nTx1GaeaY3xmDWJbD3tlNQn_Rxw-jZPZOzxb1YeN7y2qWO9qoSIAg22_SwZuOQ[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Encoding: aesgcm[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Encryption: salt=ski4AOi0Xc5HCo2zvuzDfg[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "TTL: 2419200[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Crypto-Key: dh=BGLGnvvc-_jNZuHicms4eBijG7flOSUXHAte5GF2GtEQ1viZoL_NlzakYJBGMJrHHEbuxr76mPh8mAF0fZ2KFCo=;p256ecdsa=BKjlmDj7I5JkC3I2clsddfl7rklur8OIIx8_EKvDfpdrebwKRebZChSCIqKp64nkkyq4IWpUlVoDQ2CKK4axUjo[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/octet-stream[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 202[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: web.push.apple.com[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpAsyncClient/4.1.4 (Java/1.8.0_362)[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.882 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "[0xffffffc6][0x8]1_[0xfffffff1][0xffffffaa][0x8]1m[0xfffffff3][0xffffffd9]0:[0xffffffd8][0x1d]2Y[0xffffff9c][0xffffffae][0x8][0xfffffffe]gVs[0xffffffec][0xffffffcd]~[0x15][0xffffff8e][0xc][0xfffffff7][0xffffff83][0x12]B[0xffffffcc]y[0xffffffd8][0xffffff8d]}C{mCL[0xffffffee]0Z[0xffffffc3][0xffffff9a])20[0xffffffc8]G[0xffffffdb]<t[0x6]a[0xffffff84]q[0x0][0xffffffc8][0xffffffa0][0xffffffe3][0xffffff95][0xffffff82][0xffffffdf]3'[0xffffffeb][0xffffffbf][0xffffffa7]H$\1[0xffffffaf]E[0xffffffb4]0[0xffffffbe][0xb]3[0xffffffdf]W[0x5],[0xffffffed][0xffffffeb]dR[0xffffffd6][0xffffffc5]Mk[0xffffffc7][0xffffffbe][0x18]%[0xffffffd5]A[0xffffffec]~f[0xffffffd5][0xfffffff3](u[0xffffffc4]J{kKG[0xffffff8f]7NaZ<1:F@[0xf][0xffffff97][0xffffffca].K[0xffffffea][0xffffffb1][0xfffffffd][0xfffffff6][0xffffff9d][0xffffffc9][0x7][0xffffff86]r[0xffffff95]S[0xfffffff4][0xffffffba]3[0xffffffe7][0xfffffff8][0xffffffd0];[0xffffffce][0xffffffd1][0xffffffce][0xffffffe7][0xffffffd1][0xffffffa2][0xffffffa0][0xffffffba]Z[0xffffff80][0xffffffa6][0x2]X[0xffffff9c][0xffffff91][0xffffffda][0xffffff98][0x12][0xffffffda]z[0xffffffe0]q7[0xffffffa9]F[0x0][0xffffffe7]3R[0xffffff9d]M\v:xU[0xffffffa4][0xffffffa6][0xffffffdf];na[0x1c][0xffffffe1]>[0xffffff82](2[0xffffffcf]-![0xffffff83][0xffffffd7][0xffffffc9]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.883 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] o.a.h.i.nio.client.InternalIODispatch    : http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE] Request ready
2023-02-23 16:32:05.883 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] h.i.n.c.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl : http-outgoing-0 10.154.0.20:56270<->17.188.172.94:443[ACTIVE][r:w][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: Event cleared [w]
2023-02-23 16:32:05.975 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] h.i.n.c.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl : http-outgoing-0 10.154.0.20:56270<->17.188.172.94:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: 158 bytes read
2023-02-23 16:32:05.975 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.975 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.975 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "content-length: 24[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.975 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "apns-id: 3253F680-762D-BC6F-9218-CB0F250A9142[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.975 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.975 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "{"reason":"BadJwtToken"}"
2023-02-23 16:32:05.978 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
2023-02-23 16:32:05.978 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
2023-02-23 16:32:05.978 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-length: 24
2023-02-23 16:32:05.978 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << apns-id: 3253F680-762D-BC6F-9218-CB0F250A9142
2023-02-23 16:32:05.978 DEBUG 17412 --- [/O dispatcher 1] o.a.h.i.nio.client.InternalIODispatch    : http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE(24)] Response received
```

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of at this stage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me the problem was missing or incorrectly formatted `sub` parameter. It is NOT mandatory according to the protocol documentation, but Apple (and actually Mozilla as well) decided that it's required. Apple states, that one of the reasons of 403 `BadJwtToken` is this: "The JWT subject claim isn’t a URL or mailto:." (See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_web_push_notifications_in_safari_and_other_browsers)) When I started providing the `sub` parameter as `mailto:%my_email_address%`, everything works fine for me. You may look at the discussion [here](https://github.com/web-push-libs/webpush-java/issues/201#issuecomment-1443258546)
I hope it will help.

Comment: This was it Really can't believe this was so simple in the end. I actually did have subject, but it was malformed (or at least malformed according to Apple's restrictions). My subject was in the format "mailto: <mail@example.com>". Apple doesn't like the space or the angle brackets.

Comment: Hi, Andrej. 
This answer really helpful after 20 hours investigating and solved my problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Nice! Solve my problem using `mailto:%my_email_address%` in parameter subject